# libGDX / html game shows black screen when reloading in Firefox

Tags: java, gradle, gwt, libgdx

I've made some class project with libGDX, is a desktop simulator incrusted in a website.

Despite libGDX / Gradle / GWT compiling for html5 could be so tricky sometimes, at the end everything works as expected... except in firefox, don't know why, sometimes when reloading the game/page it turns into a black screen that is only solved by cleaning cookies (and also deleting your game saved , as it is saved in Preferences). This never happens in Edge or Chrome..

What could be causing that? is something about saving data methods? Or more related to OpenGL/ Js environment?

Here is the game: https://devxmachina.000webhostapp.com/

Here full code (I know is a mess just testing):https://github.com/VladScv/DxM_Game_v3

Here my save/load data methods:

```
  private void getSavedData() {

    if (preferences.contains("GameEvent_Data")) {

        savedData = true;
        currentMoney = preferences.getInteger("currentMoney");
        currentDecade = DxM_Game.EventDecade.valueOf(preferences.getString("currentDecade"));
        decadeProgress = preferences.getFloat("decadeProgress");
        currentReputation = preferences.getInteger("currentReputation");
        userName = preferences.getString("userName");
        testFinalResults = preferences.getString("testResults");
        testAnswer = testFinalResults.split("\n");
        sound = preferences.getBoolean("sound");
        debugMode = preferences.getBoolean("debug");

    } else {

        savedData = false;
        currentMoney = 0;
        currentDecade = DxM_Game.EventDecade.SEVENTIES;
        decadeProgress = 0.f;
        currentReputation = 100;
        testFinalResults="";
        userName = "";
    }
}

  public void saveAllData() {

    preferences.putString("GameEvent_Data", eventManager.toString());
    preferences.putInteger("currentMoney", currentMoney);
    preferences.putString("currentDecade", currentDecade.name());
    preferences.putFloat("decadeProgress", decadeProgress);
    preferences.putInteger("currentReputation", currentReputation);
    preferences.putString("userName", userName);
    preferences.putString("testResults", testFinalResults);
    preferences.putBoolean("sound", sound);
    preferences.putBoolean("debug", debugMode);
    eventManager.save_resultsArray(preferences);
    preferences.flush();
    saveGame = false;

}
```

Comment: The link to the game doesn't seem to load, from firefox or chrome.

Comment: @ColinAlworth it works for me and my colleagues, tried right now and working fine, have you even seen the default libGDX loading bar? or it doesn't loads anything?

Comment: As far as I can tell, that domain resolves to `127.0.0.1`, which is the address for a computer to talk about itself, so it seems your dns is set up only to connect to your own computer?

Comment: Actually don't know a lot about DNS or IP's :$  i'm just starting with local programming.  I'm just starting with local programming. As far as I know I only use a free webhosting where I directly pasted the files compiled by libGDX/GWT in the html/build/Dist folder as I've read in a few tutorials... "that domain resolves to 127.0.0.1" that could be causing my bug? And how to solve that? I've checked in 000webHost options and it doesn't give me any option about IP or DNS unless I park a domain name...

Comment: The 127.0.0.1 thing probably simply means that this domain was set up to help you debug your own project, but you won't be able to use the project anywhere else. It is likely unrelated. Without more information, and since edge and chrome are both the "same" to GWT, I'm guessing that something is "forgetting" to rebuild as you change browsers. More information is probably needed - I'll try to build/run the app from github sources if I get the chance, but I have no libgdx experience.

Comment: I'm sorry to report that I can't reproduce the issue with the information you've given me. I checked out your project this morning, and ran `./gradlew build :html:appRun`, and opened the game in firefox (going to http://localhost:8080/), entered my name, answered some questions, started the game, and then refreshed the page - it seemed to correctly start again, and still knew my name? It seems to work the same in Chrome. Perhaps you can add more specifics about the problem, or how you encounter it? There is a gwt community at https://gitter.im/gwtproject/gwt who may be able to help too.